# How to obtain the ResNet component of the Tensorflow implementation of SimCLR v2?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, embedding, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I am currently trying to create embeddings of images by passing them through pre-trained Neural Networks and getting the values obtained at the last layer just before the fully-connected ones. I did not have much problem doing it with Pytorch implementations of other Neural Networks. However, I am stuck with the Tensorflow implementation of SimCLR v2 and do not know how to proceed.

The official repo of SimCLR v2 is this one: https://github.com/google-research/simclr

And the paper is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10029v2

If I understood correctly the paper and the code, this architecture is composed of a backbone ResNet as well as a projection head. In my case, I am not interested in the projection head and just want to obtain the results of the output of the ResNet model.

Looking at the code in the colabs, I have managed to import pre-trained SimCLR models:

```
model_path = 'gs://simclr-checkpoints-tf2/simclrv2/pretrained/r50_1x_sk0/saved_model'
saved_model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

However, I do not know what to do to get the outputs of the ResNet. In all the colabs, they only get the outputs of the projection head which I am uninterested in.

```
for x in ds.take(1):
  image = x['image']
  labels = x['label']
  logits = saved_model(image, trainable=False)['logits_sup']
  pred = tf.argmax(logits, -1)
```

Moreover, the way the model is imported makes it difficult to get the variables and layers. For instance if I try obtain a summary of the model, I have this error:

```
'_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

I also do not want to convert the weights of Tensorflow into Pytorch and import them into a pytorch ResNet.

What then would be the best way to isolate the ResNet from the overall SimCLR v2 architecture in order to get the outputs of the final layer ?